# Closing bracket and parenthesis in multline

Tags: brackets, multline

Where is an issue in my MWE with brackets when I split equation into two lines?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}



\begin{multline}
\chi(bt)=\frac{1}{\surd\bar{\pi}}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{j+1}
\frac{(\surd\bar{\pi}^{j})}{\surd\overline{(j-1)!}}
exp\left[\left(-\frac{j\alpha n_{\alpha}F}{RT}\right)
\left(E-E^{0}+\frac{RT}{\alpha n_{\alpha}F}ln
\frac{\surd\overline{\pi Db}}{k_{s}}- \right. \nonumber \\
&\left. {} -\frac{RT}{\alpha n_{\alpha}F}ln\frac{K}{1+K}\right]
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

The issue is that in the second line I get `]` at the end but not `)`.

Comment: You lost one `\right)` or `\right]`.

Comment: Right but then I get very tiny right bracket and right parenthesis in last line.

Comment: Are you sure about `\surd`?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

The simplest is to do a manual size adjustment for delimiters, with `\biggl` and `\biggr`.

I propose also another layout for the equation, which makes easier to read, in my opinion. However, you may have constraints I'm not aware of…

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
  \chi(bt)=\frac{1}{\surd\bar{\pi}}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{j+1}
  \frac{(\surd\bar{\pi}^{j})}{\surd\overline{(j-1)!}}
  \exp\left[-\frac{j\alpha n_{\alpha}F}{RT}
    \biggl(E-E^{0}+{}\right. \\ + \frac{RT}{\alpha n_{\alpha}F}\ln
    \frac{\surd\overline{\pi Db}}{k_{s}}
  \left.\left. {} -\frac{RT}{\alpha n_{\alpha}F}\ln\frac{K}{1+K}\right)\right]
\end{multline*}

\[
  \chi(bt)=\!\begin{aligned}[t]\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{j+1}
  \sqrt{\frac{\pi^j}{(j-1)!}}
  \exp j\biggl(\frac{\alpha n_{\alpha}F}{RT}
  (E^{0}-E) & - \ln
  \frac{\sqrt{\pi Db}}{k_{s}}\\[-1ex]
  & + \ln\frac{K}{1+K}\biggr)
  \end{aligned} \]

\end{document}
```

[image: make]

Answer (score 2):

(Rewrote the code after the OP noted where the missing closing parenthesis should be located.)

The code needs another `\right)` directive in order to have a chance to compile. Observe that I've moved a chunk of code from the first to the second line, both in order to avoid getting an overfull first line and to achieve a more natural grouping of the elements.

Incidentally, you should write `\exp` and `\ln`, not `exp` and `ln`. Doing so not only results in the operators being typeset in upright letters (a very common notational convention), but informs TeX about how to go about finding the correct amount of spacing to the left and right of the operator.

[image]

Incidentally, what makes you use `\surd` in some cases and `\surd\overline{...}` in others? For that matter, have you considered typing `\sqrt{...}` instead of `\surd\overline{...}`?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
\chi(bt)=\frac{1}{\surd\bar{\pi}}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{j+1}
\frac{(\surd\bar{\pi}^{j})}{\surd\overline{(j-1)!}}
\exp \left[
\left(-\frac{j\alpha n_{\alpha}F}{RT}\right) \right.  \\
\left. \times \left(E-E^{0}+\frac{RT}{\alpha n_{\alpha}F}
\ln\frac{\surd\overline{\pi Db}}{k_{s}} 
-\frac{RT}{\alpha n_{\alpha}F} \ln\frac{K}{1+K}\right) 
\right]
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No, it's not really what I need. I cannot find proper example, so I will try to explain it. I don't want ``(E-E^{0})`` but instead ``(E-E^{0}- \\
... )]``. So I need closing parenthesis for this ``E-E^{0}`` expression next to closing bracket for whole expression.
I hope, it is more clear now.

Comment: @user2300369 - Thanks for clarifying where the missing closing parenthesis needs to go. I've modified my answer accordingly. Note that I still suggest moving a chunk of the code from the first to the second line.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions, but this is not actually my book.
To pass a course on LaTeX I need to reproduce two original pages from a chosen book.